With new model of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Extensibility have somes difficulty to add validator on editor
I am learning to use the new model to create Visual Studio extensions (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Extensibility). I created an ExtensionPart that inherits from ITextViewOpenClosedListener and ITextViewChangedListener.
When called, we get an object that interfaces ITextViewSnapshot. This is good, but the official MS documentation and the examples I found only work with the Uri of this object (basically, we make a link directly to the file on disk). I was still able to implement my validator and it "works"... more or less because I do not have the modifications on the file being edited. So I highlight code that has been corrected.
My question is this: From the ITextViewSnapshot, is it possible to apply my XSD validation to the file being executed.
This is simply for training purposes. I know that directly referencing the XSD on the XML file would do the trick. But I'm mainly trying to understand how the new VS extension model works.
Thanks!
If you want to see the full code to date it's here: : Extension RXML VS Extensibility
